# How to change active key for an account?

Tags: accounts, permissions, keys

My active and owner keys are the same.
I want to change active key to be different from owner, for safety.

What command should I use?

Comment: Is it possible to set the account keys from within a smart contract action rather than calling cleos?

Comment: is there an easier way to do this for someone who is not technical?

Answer (score 9):

Looks like I found the answer I was looking for.

`cleos set account permission accountname active '{"threshold": 1, "keys": [{"key": "NEW_ACTIVE_PUBLIC_KEY", "weight": 1}]}' owner`

When having weight 1 you can simply use this alias instead:

`cleos set account permission accountname active NEW_ACTIVE_PUBLIC_KEY owner -p accountname@owner`

After, you can check that it worked with:

`cleos get account accountname`

Comment: For reference: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-set-account